# Powershell - Copy-Item to a remote share path error illegal characters in path

Tags: windows, powershell

OK, the real problem was that I was getting the path from a registry entry and then cleaning it with Regex. The very start of the path had a space in the front which I did not notice the way I was logging. I fixed this problem by using this:
    #outvar is used to build the path and comes from a registry key | Out-String
    $outvar = ($outvar -replace '\s','')

```
$localtruststore = "C:\Users\me\OneDrive\work\scripts\PS\TEST\truststore"
$servers = "SERVER1"

## remotepath is actually set by looking at a registry entry, but I am sure it is coming out like this:
$remotepath = "d$\programname\40\server\Openfire\resources\security"


#### THIS LINE CAUSES THE ERROR - I think just because of the $.
Copy-Item $localtruststore -Destination \\$server\$remotepath -Force

Copy-Item : Illegal characters in path.
At C:\Users\me\OneDrive\work\scripts\PS\TEST\chat_copy_trustore_to_remote.ps1:46 char:11
+     Copy-Item <<<<  $localtruststore -Destination \\$server\$remotepath -Force
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Copy-Item], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand
```

If I manually put the Destination in, the copy works perfectly, so this must be a simple syntax issue.

I have tried completely building the $destinationpath variable by doing these:

```
$destinationpath = "\\$server\$remotepath"    
$destinationpath = ("\\{0}\{1}" -f $server,$remotepath)
```

BOTH of these work and when I write-host the variable I get the correct \server\d$\programe...
I still get illegal character in path., char14

I have confirmed that the character referenced in the error is the exact number where the $ symbol is in the destination. it is that char number in that argument.

I ended up just breaking this in to two parts....see below..

This will copy to the admin share for the root of D.
    Copy-Item -path $localtruststore -Destination \$server\d$  -Force

Then I use this later to move the file on the remote server..
    Invoke-command -ComputerName $server {
    Copy-Item -path D:\truststore -Destination D:\Temp -Force
    }

What may or may not have complicated this is my Java Keystore files, JKS files, do not have file extensions..

Comment: (Get-ItemProperty HKCU:\Software\Dropbox -Name Installpath).installpath.trim() # You can use Get-ItemProperty to read the regkey and remove leading and trailing whitespaces with trim().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UNC paths start with double backslashes so your command should look like this:

```
$source = "C:\Users\me\OneDrive\work\scripts\PS\TEST\truststore"
$server = "server1"
$destinationpath = "\\$server\d$\programname\40\server\Openfire\resources\security"

copy-item -path $source -destination $destinationpath -verbose


Or you can do it like this:
$foldershare = "d$\programname\40\server\Openfire\resources\security"
$destinationpath = ("\\{0}\{1}" -f $server,$foldershare)
```

Comment: Where would I specify the drive? I need to use a variable for the folder path. In other words, if have a variable for the destination   folder, how do I concatenate the server with the d$ share on it?

Comment: the same way megamorf did with $server perhaps?

Comment: I added an alternative way for you.

Comment: I tried the second one. The variable $destinationpath is being created correctly as \\servername\d$\programname\folder  BUT when I go to use it with Copy-Item $localtruststore -Destination $destinationpath -Force  I still get the Illegal Characters in path errror

Comment: copy-item D:\temp\debug -Destination "\\$server\$share" -Verbose -Force # works for me

Comment: i can see that it should work.. still not working for me..maybe I will just use VBS for this part, or try a different command..

Comment: I ended up just splitting this in to two operations and I was able to use Powershell. One command to copy from my local machine to the root of the d drive, then a second command, invoked by the remote server to move the file to the correct place based on that server. Thanks for your help anyway.. Im sure this is something weird.